# Make a two-dimensions (bidimensional) matrix in javascript provided by JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, matrix

I want to get data from JSON and put that into a bidimensional matrix using JavaScript.

I get my values in JSON like this:

```
$(data).each(function(index,value){ // for each
  //getting my data values. Example: EU-New York
  var option = value.split('-'); // spliting by '-'
  var country = option[0]; // getting country
  var city = option[1]; // city

  // Here save to Javascript variable. For each Country, N cities.
}
```

Example to better understand. **For each Country, N cities**:

```
country1 > city1
         > city2
         > city3

country2 > city1
         > city2
```

Is there any way to make a two-dimensions matrix and save it temporarily in a Javascript variable?

Comment: What do you mean? It sounds like maybe you want a dictionary keyed off of the country containing a list of cities? And what, exactly, do you mean by "save"? Do you mean just save in memory? Or actually save to persistent storage?

Comment: Thanks @MattBurland I was looking for save or assign to a variable. The same that you do in your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
// Some mock data so we have something to play with
var data = [
  "US-New York",
  "US-Chicago",
  "UK-London",
  "UK-Manchester"
];

var dict = {};

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
      var split = item.split("-");
      if (!dict.hasOwnProperty(split[0])) {
          dict[split[0]] = [];
        }
        dict[split[0]].push(split[1]);

      }); 

console.dir(dict);

// stringified just so you can see what's happening.
alert(JSON.stringify(dict));

// example: get all cities in the US
alert(dict["US"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This will transform the `data` into an object like this:

```
{
    "US": [
        "New York",
        "Chicago"
    ],
    "UK": [
        "London",
        "Manchester"
    ]
}
```

Then if you want all the `US` cities, you can just get them like so:

```
var citiesInUS = dict["US"];
```

Or even:

```
var citiesInUS = dict.US;
```

Comment: Thanks @MattBurland for your help. I will try it in my code.